# Combining scripts or using one to input to the next

Tags: powershell

I have 2 Powershell scripts and they both work really well - but I now want to combine them and am not sure how to go about it.

The first script is (this provides details of apps installed from the Store):

```
Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, InstallLocation, PackageFamilyName, Target
```

The second script is (which provides the application id - which is required to launch the app through code):

```
(Get-AppxPackage -Name "*ADD PACKAGE NAME*" | Get-AppxPackageManifest).package.applications.application.id
```

If possible - I'd either want the above combined in one script where the application id could be appended to an additional column - or I'd like the first script to feed/input the second script.

EDIT: I've now updated the script based on the below:

```
    # Get packages and select needed properties
    $packages = Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, InstallLocation, 
    PackageFamilyName, Target

    # add foreach through each package 
    foreach ($package in $packages) {
    $appName = $package.Name
    $appId = (Get-AppxPackage -Name $appName | Get- 
    AppxPackageManifest).package.applications.application.id
    $batchline = "start explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\"

    # Set the Application ID to the object as a new
    $package | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 
    "ApplicationId" -Value $appId
    
    #format batch output line
    $package | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Batchfile 
    Line" -Value $batchline$appName"!"$appId
    }

    # Output (combined result)
    $packages
```

And wondered if it was possible to amend the batch output line to include the "PackageFamilyName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on this script and adapted it to the below - this now works perfectly for my use case - pulls back the package name and type and combines this into a row that can be used to create batch files - it also validates the correct type as not all use the '!App' suffix...

```
    # Function to get the app ID for a given package name
function Get-AppId {
    param (
        [string]$PackageName
    )

    # Get the app package for the given package name
    $appPackage = Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $PackageName }

    if ($appPackage) {
        return $appPackage.PackageFamilyName
    } else {
        return $null
    }
}

# Get all installed UWP programs
$installedPackages = Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { $_.IsFramework -eq $false }

if ($installedPackages.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "List of UWP programs with package name, app ID, and batch command:`n"

    # Generate a custom table with formatted columns
    $table = @()
    foreach ($app in $installedPackages) {
        $appName = $app.Name
        $appId = Get-AppId -PackageName $appName

        if ($appId) {
            $packageNameWithAppId = "$appName.$appId"

            # Get the app IDs from the app's manifest
            try {
                $ids = (Get-AppxPackageManifest $app -ErrorAction Stop).Package.Applications.Application.Id
            } catch {
                Write-Output "No IDs found for $($app.Name)" 
            }

            # Construct batch file command for each app ID
            foreach ($id in $ids) {
                $line = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Name = $appName
                    "Package Name" = $packageNameWithAppId
                    "App ID" = $id
                    "BatchFileCommand" = "start explorer.exe `shell:AppsFolder\$($appId)!$($id)"
                }
                $table += $line
            }
        }
    }

    # Output the formatted table
    $table | Format-Table -AutoSize 

} else {
    Write-Host "No installed UWP programs found."
}
```